# Как узнать родителя узла TreeView sql-запрсом

Tags: delphi, firebird

бд firebird имеет поля: Acc_id, Acc_number, Parent_id, Title.
В edit контроле ввожу номер дочернего узла, например, 2700. Как узнать что его родителем является 2000?  Или родитель узла 1125  1120?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Parent_id FROM MyTable WHERE Title = '2700'
```

Если `Title` уникальный. Если нет привязка к `Acc_id` (если я правильно понял, это первичный ключ)

```
SELECT Parent_id FROM MyTable WHERE Acc_id = 123
```

Как в узле `TreeView` хранить `id` записи разговор отдельный.

Comment: Streletz, если правильно стою на родительский узел тогда очень легко. Так и сейчас работает но как быть, например, если стою не на правильный узел 1100 а на 1000 или на 1110 и добавляю 1160? Программа "узнает" его родителя и добавляет в узле 1100. Как? Какой алгоритм?

Comment: @basti, если Вы добавляете к какому-то узлу дочерний Вы разве не знаете id этого узла? Если это узел самого верхнего уровня, тогда всё вообще элементарно (у такого узла родителя просто нет) .

Answer (score 1):

То есть тебе нужна подсказка, к какому узлу лучше добавить дочерний? Ну как-то так:

```
with recursive a (n) as (
  select cast(:N as varchar(30)) from rdb$database
  union all
  select
    case
      when n containing ' ' then left(n,char_length(n)-position(' ',reverse(n)))
      when char_length(n)=1 then 'Base'
      else left(n,char_length(n)-1)
    end
  from a
  where char_length(n)>=1 and n<>'Base')
select ac.acc_id,ac.acc_number
from a
  join accounts ac on ac.acc_number=rpad(a.n,4,'0')
fetch first 1 row only
```

Рекурсивно откусываем справа кусочек за кусочком и ищем первое, что подойдет.